# JS event handler with custom html attributes

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am revisiting/learning/unlearning what I thought I knew about custom attributes.  Most of the information I've found here is a discussion of whether they are 'acceptable' or not, but I haven't seen a discussion of my question:

If you have a collection of elements to be handled by a common event handler (say a collection of thumbnail versions of pictures, or product detail thumbnails that when clicked would populate a main product details panel), what would be the preferred method of doing this without using custom attributes, if that is not a valid approach?

Say you wanted an onclick handler that would pass a parameter to a web service, and you were storing that parameter in an attribute "productDetail", e.g:

`<img src="couchthumb.jpg" productDetail="couch_95" />`

And you wanted to do this for each of the thumbnails on your couches page.

What is the better approach if not to do it this way?

Answer (score 1):

In HTML 5, you can use "data-" attributes:

```
<img src='couchthumb.jpg' data-product-detail='couch_95'>
```

All attributes of that form are valid attributes (in HTML 5).

Another approach (if you're concerned about doing things "right", whatever that means to you) is to use the "class" attribute for things like that:

```
<img src='couchthumb.jpg' class='productDetail:couch_95'>
```

Your code would have to pull the value out with a regex or something.

Comment: Right, and thanks. What is tripping me up though, is for those who say you shouldn't use custom attributes because there should be other XHTML-compliant ways of doing it, is, what are those ways?  So if the data-* attribute is just a legitimizing of something people said was a bad practice in the first place, what is a different way of doing it?  By different, I do mean a best practice, because I can imagine a scheme where you have an intelligent name in the id, and parse the function parameter out of that or something, but I wouldn't think that is a best practice.